# "Не()сразу" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Такая фраза: "Извини, что не()сразу отвечаю". "Несразу" тут пишется слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наречия, не образованные от прилагательных с суффиксами О/Е (небогато, нелегко и т.п., т.е. которые пишутся по правилам прилагательных),пишутся с НЕ всегда раздельно!(Кроме НЕОХОТА)...

Answer (score 0):

Разве есть такое слово "несразу"? У меня на экране оно подчеркнуто красным, т.е. ошибочно!

Comment: Вот это точно не аргумент! Компьютерный редактор ошибается очень часто!. Он не различает смысл, не отличает причастие от прилагательного и даже безударные гласные не  исправляет, если есть оморформа данному слову.

Comment: Ясно, что не аргумент. Просто я такого слова не знаю. А вообще я заметила, что здешний редактор предлагает для замены весьма странные варианты. В Word они гораздо более логичные.